# SQL get the count of rows in each group when it 's not null

Tags: sql, count, group-by

i have a pretty complicated query to do, i searched for hours and i have not progress in resolving it so i am asking for your help.

Let's say I have the following table:

```
id      action_id
 1       4
 2       null
 3       6
 4       4
 5       4
 6       null
 7       null
 8       6
```

I want to get the number of action_id ignoring the repetition in each group surrounded by null values.
So the result expected is not :

```
action_id     count
 4            3
 6            2
```

but:

```
action_id     count
 4            2
 6            2
```

Is there a way to do this task ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are you trying to do it?

Comment: What RDMS are you using? (sql-server,mysql,oracel)?

Comment: I am using postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT action_id,COUNT(action_id) FROM
table1 WHERE 
ID > (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM table1 WHERE action_id IS NULL) AND
ID < (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table1 WHERE action_id IS NULL) AND
action_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY action_id;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/718c4/5)

Comment: That would result in what he does not want.

Comment: @Hamidreza : thanks for you response but my question is that i don't want the first result (3,2) , i want the second (2,2).Perhaps my question was not enough clear, sorry.

Comment: I gave you a down vote because you obviously are not reading the question correctly. He doesn't want the count of all 4's... Might have been harsh to down vote, sorry about that.

Comment: I'm so sorry my friend, you are right and i get your question now, but in your question 6 count must be 1 or 2??

Comment: Sorry for my wrong answer my friend, i edit my answer right now.

Comment: No problem, but the 6 count must be 2 because it appears 2 times in different groups.

Comment: Yes 6 appears 2 times but the last time is not surrounded by null values same as first 4.

Comment: Ok, we should treat this cases also

Comment: Take a look at SQL Fiddle, i think that one of this queries is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select action_id, count(1)
from Table1
where (id<>action_id)
and action_id is not null
group by action_id
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c2cb/3)**